Error crítico al intentar emparejar desde VS 2022 con MacBook Air
En el MacBook Air:
Versión de Xcode: 15.4
En Windows:
Versión de Visual Studio 2022: 17.10.5
VisualStudio.Mac 1.0
Xamarin 17.10.0.110
SDK de Xamarin.iOS y Xamarin.Mac 16.4.0.23
Recibo los siguientes mensajes:
Conectando… Verificando la configuración del host para conectarse a ‘xxx’ …
Conectando… Verificando la configuración de SSH…
Conectando… Inicializando entorno…
Una vez que recibo el mensaje "Inicializando entorno," Visual Studio 2022 deja de funcionar y no puedo hacer nada más hasta que se cierre o devuelva errores. Lo extraño es que esto no sucedió la primera vez que me emparejé con el Mac, pero comenzó a pasar al día siguiente. Pido disculpas porque sé que este no es el lugar para reportar esto, pero cuando intento reportarlo como se indica para VS, obtengo un error de pérdida de conexión con VS.
Este error (ver imagen) ocurrió en algunos de mis intentos de emparejar con el Mac.
